# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docopt'

Tags: python, macos, docopt

I have installed docopt by typing `pip3 install docopt` and now it is well installed: You can see it on the list

```
umr5558-c02gl0y6drjm:Concatenate etudiant$ pip3 list
Package         Version
--------------- -------
biopython       1.71   
buildozer       0.34   
cycler          0.10.0 
docopt          0.6.2  
kiwisolver      1.0.1  
matplotlib      2.2.2  
nose            1.3.7  
numpy           1.14.2 
pexpect         4.5.0  
pip             10.0.0 
ptyprocess      0.5.2  
pyparsing       2.2.0  
python-dateutil 2.7.2  
pytz            2018.4 
scipy           1.0.1  
setuptools      39.0.1 
sh              1.12.14
six             1.11.0 
virtualenv      15.2.0 
wheel           0.30.0
```

But when I try to import docoport from docopt on python3 it raises:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docopt'

Does someone have an idea?

Here is the path:

```
umr5558-c02gl0y6drjm:Concatenate etudiant$ pip3.6 install docopt
Requirement already satisfied: docopt in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.6.2)
```

Here is the import section:

```
from Bio import codonalign 
from Bio.Align import MultipleSeqAlignment 
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord 
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC 
from Bio.Seq import Seq from Bio import AlignIO 
from Bio import pairwise2 
from Bio.codonalign.codonseq import _get_codon_list, CodonSeq, cal_dn_ds 
import scipy 
from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline 
from Bio.Align import MultipleSeqAlignment 
from scipy.linalg import expm 
from Bio import SeqIO 
import sys 
import numpy as np 
from docopt import docopt
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one version of python installed ?

Comment: At least 2: 
Python 2.7.10 and  Python 3.6.4
But is it a problem since I run Python3?

Comment: I don't see another possible reason... Howard do y ou start your script ? with a command line ? By clicking on the .py file ? Which system do you work on ? Macos, win, Unix ?

Comment: I have a script with one function which I call by giving some arguments on the commande line, I already use some modules such as Bio, sys etc and they work well. I'm on MacBookPro and yes it is a .py file. Here is an exemple of the command line I use to run my script: python3 divergence.py concatenate_0035_fna_renamed.fst concatenate_0042_fna_renamed.fst 
concatenate_0035_faa_renamed.fst concatenate_0042_faa_renamed.fst dn_ds.out ML

Comment: Can you add the part of the script where you import this module ? You should have something like this `from docopt import docopt` according to the doc.

Comment: here are my first lines: `
`from Bio import codonalign
from Bio.Align import MultipleSeqAlignment
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio import pairwise2
from Bio.codonalign.codonseq import _get_codon_list, CodonSeq, cal_dn_ds
import scipy
from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline
from Bio.Align import MultipleSeqAlignment
from scipy.linalg import expm
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import numpy as np

from docopt import docopt`

Comment: So, yes I used : `from docopt import docopt`

Comment: Can you add the part where you call this library so I can try to reproduce you error ?

Comment: It is just at the beginning, let's say I have a file.py : I juste write : from docopt import docopt , and when I execute : python3 file.py it raises: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docopt' , the same if I try directly on python3

Comment: I can't reproduce this error, everything works fine for me... Sorry =(

Comment: Finally I found my mistake, I had to change my pythonpath.

Answer (score 2):

**Hello
Try it**

```
sudo apt install python3-docopt
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and this is how I solved it:
I also had installed docopt via `pip install docopt`, and I have both python 2 and 3 in my mac.
 The problem is that docopt is installed for python 3, but when running the .py file in terminal, it ran in python 2 by default.
 Just add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to the very beginning of your .py file, and it should fix your issue.

Comment: I don't know why, but I also had to do `sudo pip3 install docopt`, not just `pip3 install docopt`.